# MSK modulation waveform plotting

Tags: python, spyder

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import pi
from numpy import sin
from numpy import cos
from numpy import r_
fH = 1800  
fL=1200
j=0
k=0
input = np.random.random_integers(0,1,7) 
print input
l=len(input)
if (l%2!=0):
   e=(l-1)/2
   o=(l/2)+1
else:
   e=(l/2)
   o=(l/2)
t = np.arange(0,l+1)
even=np.zeros(e)
odd=np.zeros(o)
for i in range(0,l):
   if i%2==0:
      odd[j]=input[i]
      j=j+1
   else:
      even[k]=input[i]
      k=k+1
print odd
print even 
#fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
#print "Current size:", fig_size
#fig_size[0] = 10
#fig_size[1] = 10
x=np.array(odd)
y=np.array(even)
plt.plot(t,x)
plt.plot(t,y)
```

[I want to implement MSK modulation using python using this EXOR logic as mentioned in figure. Kindly help me out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLbmx.png)
Also when i run the above code i get error that x abd y must have same first dimension and the plot of even and odd bits doesn't work.